# iPhone UITextField and UIButton in one grey frame

Tags: iphone, ios5, uibutton, uitextfield

I would like to create something like this:

[image]

I would like to place an UITextField with an UIButton into one grey frame, and I would like the button's border to be contained by this grey frame.

Please somebody show me some sample code for this!

Thx!

Comment: I have tried to build it in IB, put up an UIView and put the 2 other view onto it, but I can't find the good attributes. Sorry for you had to read my question...

Comment: And I didn't write this post because I don't want to try or I'm lazy or it is better for me if I use the code of somebody else or etc. I write it because I don't know how should I do it, and I thought that a place where people come to ask help, will be a good place...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** Use a `UIImageView` of required rect. Set the background image to the gradient gray colour image.

```
 UIImageView*myImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame];
 [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grayBackground.png"];
 [self.view addSubview:myImageView];
```

**2.** Use a  round rect. `UITextField` make it a subview of the image view. Use a place holder as "Write a reply..." make it a subview to your imageview.

```
UITextField*myField=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:yourRect];
[myField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
[myField setPlaceholder:@"Write a reply..."];
[myImageView addSubview:myField];
```

**3.** Use a `UIButton` with type `Custom` and the send image as its background image, make it a subview to your imageview.

```
UIButton*myButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton setFrame:yourRect]
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sendImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myImageView addSubView:myButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to create title bar with grey background and delete the title.and place textfield and button which u want to place it.configure the size and button outside the  title bar and drag it to the title bar..u'll get like the image which u have got.

[image]